# How to find the differential equation that has the solution $u=f(x+\frac{y}{z},y+\frac{x}{z})$?

Tags: differential-equations, homework

I should use partial derivatives to find the differential equation that has the following solution:

$ u=f(x+\frac{y}{z},y+\frac{x}{z})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are infinitely many possibilities, naturally. The simplest one is a linear ansatz,
$$
(\alpha\partial_x+\beta\partial_y+\gamma\partial_z) u=0
$$
i.e.,

```
α D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], x] + β D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], y] + γ D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], z] // Simplify
```

which yields the equations

```
{z α + z^2 β - x γ == 0, z^2 α + z β - y γ == 0}
```

with solution
$$
\beta \to -\frac{\alpha  (y-x z)}{y z-x},\quad\gamma \to -\frac{\alpha  (z^3-z)}{x-y z}
$$
Of course, one parameter is arbitrary since the equation is linear. We can take $\alpha=x-yz$ to make the equation look as simple as possible,

```
(x - y z) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], x] + (y - x z) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], y] + (z - z^3) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], z] // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

Final answer is
$$
 (x-y z)\partial_xu+ (y-x z)\partial_yu+z(1-z^2)\partial_zu=0
$$

Comment: And what's the point of answering  such irrelevant question, which is not even about Mathematica?

Comment: @yarchik I interpreted the question as: how to solve this using Mathematica. Whether this was actually OP's intention or not does not seem all that relevant to me.

Comment: What is relevant, however, is that the question should show at least a little bit of work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a PDE at all, since the arguments of  the unknown function must be variables, and Mathematica says it in "The length of the derivative operator Derivative[0,1] in \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"f\", TagBox[RowBox[{\"(\", RowBox[{\"0\", \",\", \"1\"}], \")\"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None][x + \*FractionBox[\(y\), \(z\)], y + \*FractionBox[\(x\), \(z\)]]\) is not the same as the number of arguments." when `DSolve[(x - y z) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], x] + (y - x z) D[
     f[x + y/z, y + x/z], y] + (z - z^3) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], z] == 
  0, f, {x, y, z}]` is executed.

Comment: @user64494 Here $f$ is not the unknown, but rather the solution. You are not supposed to execute that command, instead you should use `DSolve[(x - y z) D[u[x, y, z], x] + (y - x z) D[u[x, y, z], y] + (z - z^3) D[u[x, y, z], z] == 0, u, {x, y, z}]` (which, MMA does not seem to be able to solve in finite time).

Comment: In any case, `(x - y z) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], x] + (y - x z) D[      f[x + y/z, y + x/z], y] + (z - z^3) D[f[x + y/z, y + x/z], z] ==    0` is not a PDE.

Comment: @user64494 Indeed, it is not a PDE, it is a trivial identity, just like $x+(-2x)/2=0$.

Comment: You are probably right with `(x - y z) D[u[x, y, z], x] + (y - x z) D[u[x, y, z], y] + (z - z^3) D[u[x, y, z], z] == 0`.

Comment: That should be "The final answer is" (or just leave it as "Final answer:", which is colloquial even if informal).